# Limitar cantidad de resultados en CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Voy aprendiendo CakePHP y me surgió esta duda, si quiero poner mi `limit` para que tenga rango de inicio y largo, ¿cómo sería?

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all',
                array('conditions' => array(
                    'post_visible !=' => '0'
                    ),
                'limit' => '0,10', 
                'order' => 'id'
                )       
            );
```

Actualmente lo tengo así pero el limite me lo pone como 0.

Lo intenté de esta forma: `'limit' => '0'.','.'10'`.

Answer (score 1):

Se establece solamente el límite.  Y por default te ordena por id, esto no haría falta.

probá así:

```
$post = $this->Post->find('all')
->where(['post_visible !=' => '0'])
->limit('10');
```

Acá tenés la documentación de Cake, leé sin miedo, vas a ir entendiendo!

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Nico, agradecemos tu contribución!, ayúdanos por favor a tener mejores respuestas en el sitio, agrega más detalles a tu respuesta, una explicación, etc!. revisa [answer], saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El `limit` solo recibe un valor no un rango, si lo que necesitas es paginar utiliza el metodo `paginate()` del framework le pasas como parámetro de a cuantos registros vas a paginar

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all',
        array('conditions' => array(
            'post_visible !=' => '0'
            ),
        'limit' => 10, 
        'order' => 'id'
        )       
    );
```

si lo necesitas para otra cosa puedes hacer la consulta find all luego recorrer con un for los registros del 1-10 y realizas la lógica que necesites con estos registros. 
Puedes recibir en tu for estas variables de rangos y ya se las pasas desde donde tu quieras y los vas modificando.